# Pass the data between admin and frontend controllers

Tags: magento

So I'm making a GET request from admin to frontend controller and I need to pass the same data twice over this request within two different ways and compare the sent values on frontend. The first way is GET request. So I can simply pass the parameter via url. 
Now I need the second way. I'm not able to use session models since admin and frontend sessions have different scopes.
The question is where I can store the data in the admin model/controller/block/observer to get it on frontend. Database and cookies (or tmp files) isn't solution for me.

Here is the simple scheme what I need to do:

[image: Scheme]

So, my final task is to make urls with dynamic keys on admin site (urls go to the frontend) but always check the key actuality on frontend. Actually, I need to save the generated value for the short time while it's actual.

Any suggestions are appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the same data twice over your request?

Comment: I need to send the key over GET request and compare with the same key sent some other way. Second way should execute only on the server side (for example, sessions). It's for security purposes to check sent url key with the system key which is depending on admin session id. Controller for the url is a frontend router.

Comment: You will get better advice if you can discuss what you are testing (rendered output, number of elements involved, etc.). FWIW, there is no reason that you cannot instantiate your controller class instance in your adminhtml action controller and work with its methods.

Comment: Ben, thanks. I've added some explanations to the question.